# Build targets in VS 2017 only called once (for my lack of a better explanation)

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I recently changed to Vs 2017 and discovered a strange behavior with Msbuild - in that simple project file below, the "Prebuild" target is only called once when the project is loaded. After that, you may hit the Build button for eternity but the "Prebuild" target is never invoked.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="echo Test" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The same happens to targets with Inputs/Outputs attributes that I use for lex/yacc integration.

Any idea why?

Comment: It only runs when a build is necessary.  It is never necessary when you don't have any source files that need rebuilding.

Comment: Hans - yes but with your argument, wouldn't it also be unnecessary in the first place? I'd would by into when we talking about the "AfterBuildEvent" but not the "PreBuiltEvent" as this behavior would render any pre-built step useless considering that an arbitrary per-built step may update files that are later to be compiled.

Comment: And, more interestingly, it works with charm in VS 2015.

Comment: It's a different project system with a new iteration of the up-to-date check so you may see different results. If you have been using project.json before, that never had a good up-to-date check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project system in VS performs an "up-to-date check" that tries to save build times by not calling MSBuild if it doesn't think that any files affecting the build have changed. So if your project is considered "up to date", no msbuild targets will be called. A "Rebuild" however will clean and build the project.

If you need to add additional input to the up-to-date check, you can use additional `UpToDateCheckInput` items to signal to visual studio that it should call MSBuild if these files change:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <UpToDateCheckInput Include="sample.txt" />
  <!-- e.g. if you are transforming markdown files -->
  <UpToDateCheckInput Include="doc/**/*.md" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PrintSomething" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="In a before build target" />
</Target>
```

Alternatively, you can disable the up-to-date check for the .NET Core / Standard project system in the options by unchecking the corresponding checkbox:

[image]

Comment: I can only hope being able to give such a useful answer to the crowd on a topic more "mine" - thank you, Martin. When I mark the lex/yacc files as "UpToDateCheckInput" it works as expected.